# How can I convert a usize to a single char?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

For an exercise I'm doing for [Exercism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exercism) (the [minesweeper](http://exercism.io/exercises/rust/minesweeper/readme) task), I need to convert an `usize` to a `char` in order to insert it into a `std::string::String`.

To describe the problem in minimal lines of code:

```
let mut s = String::from("   ");
let mine_count: usize = 5; // This is returned from a method and will be a value between 1 and 8.
s.insert(0, _______); // So I get: "5  " at the underscores I do:
```

The way I'm currently doing this as:

```
 mine_count.to_string().chars().nth(0).unwrap(); // For example: '2'
```

Or see the [full example in the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e9fdf3f5de59a2389ebb922b4b64d21d&version=stable). Somehow this doesn't strike me as elegant.

I've also tried:

```
 mine_count as char; // Where mine_count is of type u8
```

However, when adding `mine_count` to a `std::string::String`, it turns up as - for example - `\u{2}` and not simply `'2'`:

```
let mine_count: u8 = 8;
s.insert(0, mine_count as char);
println!("{:?}", s);
```

The output:

```
"\u{8}   "
```

Reproduced [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a2d8f41dc6a919c47b005de22d5e3bbb&version=stable).

Are there other ways to achieve the goal of converting an integer in the range of 1..8 to a single character (`char`)?

Comment: As a sidenote, why `i8` and not `u8`?

Comment: @E_net4 I've added three lines of code with the minimal amount of code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've changed the question. The reason I'm not using `u8` is because it doesn't work as I would have expected within a `String`.

Comment: @E_net4 what do you mean? I think I'm clear enough as it is.

Comment: The first link is broken (404).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However when adding `mine_count` to a `std::string::String` it turns up as - for example - `\u{2}` and not simply `'2'`.

This is the difference between the `char` containing the scalar value `2` and a `char` containing the actual character `'2'`. The first few UTF-8 values, like in ASCII text encoding, are reserved for control characters, and do not portray something visible. What made it appear as `\u{2}` in this context is because you printed the string with [debug formatting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) (`{:?}`). If you try to print the same string with plain formatting:

```
let mut s = String::from("   ");
let mine_count: u8 = 8;
s.insert(0, mine_count as char);
println!("{}", s);
```

The output will contain something that wasn't meant to be printed, and so might either show a placeholder character or not appear at all (reproducible [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=464a20854e63de24c1e9d5f97ca6589e&version=stable)).

In order to represent a single-digit number as the respective character: (1) First make sure that `mine_count` is within the intended limits, either by recoverable errors or hard assertions. (2) Then, transform the number by translating it to the numeric digit character domain.

```
assert!(mine_count > 0);
assert!(mine_count < 9);
let mine_char = (mine_count + b'0') as char;
s.insert(0, mine_char);
println!("{}", s);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b0cc17bbc921e08664d9e858fbab34c9&version=stable)

Answer (score 12):

I suggest using [`char::from_digit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/fn.from_digit.html) together with a cast necessary to use it (`as u32`):

```
use std::char;

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("   ");
    let mine_count: u8 = 8; // or i8 or usize
    s.insert(0, char::from_digit(mine_count as u32, 10).unwrap());

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Are there other ways to achieve the goal of converting an integer in the range of 1..8 to a single character

Use a lookup table:

```
const LABELS: [char; 9] = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];

fn main() {
    LABELS[6_usize];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let’s do it this way:

```
let data = 10;
let result = char::from_digit(data as u32, 10);

println!("{}", result); // Using the println! macro from the standard library
```

Comment: this adds nothing to the other example of from_digit